# Usage in defining an action because of someone else

Tags: american-english

I was at the bar and got a beer because my buddy typically drank them.

I stated "I ordered this beer in his image". But I feel there is an expression to say "I performed this action because it's typical of someone I know well."

Any thoughts?

Comment: it isn't clear what you mean-  do you mean that you ordered a beer because your buddy typically orders them and you wanted to do the same thing your buddy does, or do you mean that you ordered a beer because you expected your buddy would end up drinking it for you?

Answer (score 1):

You'd be more likely to say you ordered it in your buddy's *honor*. (Or *in deference to* your buddy. Or *out of respect for* your buddy. There are lots of things you could say in this vein.)